# Left join table with max value and other column from second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables with structure similar to this:

```
table1
ID |Field1|Field2

table2
ID|Table1_ID|Date|Notice
```

I need to left join these tables in MS Access SQL based on max date from second table, but also to include 'Notice' field in new table, so result should be like this:

```
ID|Field1|Field2|Max_Date|Notice
```

I can join tables based on max date like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t2.Max_date
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN
[SELECT Table1_ID, MAX(Date) AS Max_date 
FROM table2
GROUP BY Table1_ID] AS t2
ON t1.ID = t2.Table1_ID
```

How can I include 'Notice' field in this query too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOIN` again:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Field1, t1.Field2, t2m.Max_date, t2.Notice
FROM (table1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT Table1_ID, MAX(Date) AS Max_date 
       FROM table2
       GROUP BY Table1_ID
      ) AS t2m
      ON t1.ID = t2m.Table1_ID
     ) LEFT JOIN
     table2 as t2
     ON t2.Table1_ID = t2m.Table1_ID AND t2.Date = t2m.Max_Date
```